# /dev/fd/ socket or pipe links fail, NOT missing /dev/fd link

Tags: bitbake, openembedded

This single line works fine from a command line shell:

```
echo hello | /bin/bash -c 'x() { ls -l $1 >&2; strace -f tee $1 ; } &>/tmp/err ; x >( sleep 2)'
```

but fails if run as part of a bitbake recipe, the attempt to open the substituted /dev/fd/63 fails.

/dev/fd is properly a symlink to /proc/self/fd under bitbake

Under a normal environment, strace shows this behaviour from tee as it tries to open /dev/fd/63

```
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/fd/62", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
...
```

But under bitbake it is a lot more complicated:

```
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD], [], 8) = 0
lstat("/dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4040, ...}) = 0
lstat("/dev/fd", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=13, ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD], [HUP USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD], 8) = 0
readlink("/dev/fd", "/proc/self/fd", 4096) = 13
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [HUP USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
lstat("/proc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("/proc/self", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD], [HUP USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD], 8) = 0
readlink("/proc/self", "11481", 4096)   = 5
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [HUP USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
lstat("/proc/11481", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("/proc/11481/fd", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0500, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("/proc/11481/fd/63", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0300, st_size=64, ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD], [HUP USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD], 8) = 0
readlink("/proc/11481/fd/63", "pipe:[21000117]", 4096) = 15
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [HUP USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
lstat("/proc/11481/fd/pipe:[21000117]", 0x7ffce055eef0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/proc/11481/fd/pipe:[21000117]", 0x7ffce055efc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/11481/fd/pipe:[21000117]", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

All this readlink stuff is the problem, it can't safely do that on pipe nodes of /dev/fd/*

pseudo has decided to do something different when opening a file; why doesn't it just open it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in psuedo, used by bitbake for it's fakeroot environment.

Reported as pseudo bug: https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13483

This simple command works normally but fails under pseudo:

```
bash -c 'cat <( echo hello )'
```

It's going to fail until pseudo is fixed, to not dereference "broken" symlinks to the limit when opening files. i.e. doesn't try to open the broken link, but instead the last working link.